# My Spring boot application not fetching the certificate from the keystore in application's resource path

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, ssl, keycloak, keystore

My SpringBoot application uses Keycloak for authentication validation. The Keycloak URL is SSL-based.
When I am adding the .cer file in the JDK's lib/cacerts, then it's working fine. But when I am adding the .cer file in the Keystore I created, which is placed in the resource folder, doesn't read that.
Kindly help me with this.

Please note: I have added the Keystore details in the application.YAML file as well as I am using custom RestTemplate bean.

Comment: did you have someting like `server.ssl.key-store=classpath:cert.p12` in your application.yml or properties ?

Comment: Yes, I have. And even I created trust-store also separately. Still I am getting PKIX path building failed if i dont place the certificate in cacert

Comment: it's gonna be nice if you add the stacktrace and the structor of your project just to know the right error and understand more